# Domino Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a Domino server v8.5.3. FixPack 6 with the Interim fix 853FP6HF3180_W32 and I have to send emails through smtp.office365.com via SSL. I have enabled the SSL negotiadted over TCP/IP port in the configuration document and the SMTP outbound (port 25) negotiated SSL.

I get the next error:

Error transferring to outlook-xxxxxxxx.OFFICE365.COM; SMTP Protocol Returned a Permanent Error 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.outlook.com]

Comment: Are you trying to use smtp.office365.com as the outbound relay for all emails sent by this Domino server?

Comment: I would suggest asking this on Server Fault, since it is a server configuration question, not a development question.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Yes, I use this Domino server for all emails.

Comment: Okay. This is definitely a ServerFault question, not a StackOverflow question. Your outbound relay through Office365.com is requiring you to authenticate your sessions. There are configuration settings on your Domino server for that. You'll need to configure an office365 account name and password to use for that, as the Domino server obviously can't get at your users' Office365 account info.